# Deploy server on Vercel

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I am following a tutorial from [CJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnEH9tYLxLk&t=4560s) and he deploys his server with `now`.

The tutorial is not anymore up to date, since now has been changed to vercel. And I do not know how to work with vercel. Can you guide me through the process? I have a backend and a frontend. The way I understood CJ, is to deploy the server with now and this other [Tutorial](https://codingshiksha.com/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-serverless-node-js-express-app-with-zeit-now-vercel-cloud-platform-full-tutorial/) also uses `now`.

my server at velcer: [link to velcer app](https://radiototem-ae2iboqsb.vercel.app/)

**vercel json**

```
{
    "name": "my-mongodb-api",
    "builds": [{ "src": "index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }],
    "version": 2,
    "env": {
      "MONGODB_URI": "@my-mongodb-uri"
    }
  }
```

**package json**

```
{
  "name": "vermittlungsprojekt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Kunstmuseum Basel",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bad-words": "^3.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.1.3",
    "monk": "^7.3.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "Luis M Luethi",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**server code**

```
// start server: npm run dev
// 

const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const monk = require("monk");
const Filter = require('bad-words');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

 


const app = express();


const db = monk( 'localhost/beitraege'); /*process.env.my-mongo-uri ||*/
const posts = db.get("post");
const filter = new Filter();


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
       res.json({
           message: "POST"
       });
});

app.get("/beitraege", (req, res)=> {
    posts
        .find()
        .then(posts => {
            res.json(posts)
        })

})

function isValidPost(post){
    return post.name && post.name.toString().trim() !== "" &&
        post.content && post.content.toString().trim() !=="";
}

app.use(rateLimit({
    windowMs: 30 * 1000, // 30 sec
    max: 1 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
  }));

app.post("/beitraege", (req, res) => {
    if (isValidPost(req.body)){
        const post = {
            name: filter.clean(req.body.name.toString()),
            content: filter.clean(req.body.content.toString()),
            created: new Date()
        };
        //console.log(post);
        posts
            .insert(post)
            .then(createdPost => {
                 res.json(createdPost);
                  })
            .catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject();
        })
        
    }else {
        res.status(422);
        res.json({
           message: "Hey, Titel und Inhalt werden benötigt!" 
        });
    }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:5000');
});
```

Comment: Breaking my head for the same problem, if you find any solutions please tell

Comment: I switched to heroku, there it worked. I do not know what vercel offers, but they do no support node servers

Comment: Is it? but for me it worked, https://api-goloop.vercel.app . You just have to make little tweaks to your vercel.json

Answer (score 0):

once you deploy your code to vercel, you need to :

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

The scenario expect that `index.js` you mention on the `package.json` to be under the `./src` folder

- You probably need to run the server on port 80
- You need to verify this server runs without problems on local machine.
- Since you are using the `builds` `vercel.json` option, you need to ensure all the dependencies, as `node_modules` etc are uploaded to vercel, either by deploying file from the `vercel-cli`, or using some pipeline or CI action.